# Pass queried Flask data to specific looped divs that are queried from db

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Noob here. I have a database in which there are multiples instances of the same entries in particular columns. I've queried the db to get count of how many times an entry is presented with in the column. Within my template I looped through distinct instances within the db data and have the specific divs associated or shown on webpage. Within each div I need to show the total number of instances ( Which will be total number of calls technically ) within each div. This is the part I've been banging my head on.

Since there is no actual column within db that shows number of calls, I've created a query that gets number of instances of my specified column. I've tried appending these totals to an array as well as a dictionary and passing it to my template. But upon iterating through the list within my specified dynamically created div, it displays all of my totals. I know there's a better way of doing this.

Here's the route:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reports():
form = ReportConfig()

location = Cdr.query.with_entities(Cdr.src).distinct().limit(9).all()

call_dict = {}
numberofcalls = 0

for x in location:
    total_calls = Cdr.query.filter_by(src=x.src).all()
    for y in total_calls:
        numberofcalls+=1
    call_dict[x.src] = numberofcalls
    print('The number of calls for ' + x.src, ':', numberofcalls)
print(call_dict)

return render_template('reports.html', title='Home', form=form, location=locations_, numofcalls= call_dict)
```

Here is the template that shows the div that's created from info from db. as well as where I need to enter the total number.

```
                     <div class='col-4'>
                        <div>
                            <!-- I need the total number of calls here -->
                            {% for num in numofcalls%}
                            <p>{{numofcalls[num]}}</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Test</p>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Test</p>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Average</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

I can't really describe this well in the Title. But please advise me best practice or point me in the right direction. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can't help with your specific problem sorry, but you should be able to remove your second for-loop by using the `count` function i.e. `total_calls = Cdr.query.filter_by(src=x.src).count()`.

Comment: @PGHE Thank you, less code is good code.